# Completely block Spotify sign-up from iOS authorization flow

Tags: ios, xcode, spotify, url-scheme

We are trying to get an iOS app approved to go into the AppStore.  We are leveraging parts of the Spotify API in our app, so are using the Spotify web authorization flow.

On the sign in page provided by Spotify, it shows 'sign up' links as well as the sign in links.  Apple did not like this, as it violated 'Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase' as we were promoting other apps within ours.  We found the adding `nosignup` and `nolinks` request parameters removed these links:
https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Fapi.xxxx.com%2Fapi%2Fmobile%2Fspotify%2Fauthenticate%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-currently-playing&response_type=code&nosignup=true&nolinks=true

We're once again being rejected.  We have an App Store icon appearing in the returned response, encouraging users to download the Spotify app.  This is a violation of 'Guideline 3.2.2 - Business - Other Business Model Issues', imitating the functionality of the App Store!  The above request parameters are undocumented from what I can see, and were found only by sniffing the traffic between existing apps.

Is there another request parameter to turn off this App Store logo or any other way to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in future...
We found that Spotify modifies the web authentication for different user agents.  So if you browse to the auth screen in a desktop browser, you won't see the App Store logo appearing.  How does this help the case above, where we're using mobile?  Simple, override the user-agent header in the web request.  Done!
We override with `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0` and it works a charm.